# How to display Greek Character when running from cmd

Tags: java, cmd, character-encoding, fileoutputstream, bufferedwriter

I have made a program that scraps a website and extracts text and writes it in a .txt file. When I run my program from Intelij Idea every line is printed correctly in greek. But when I run the jar file from cmd the greek text is written as jibberish.

```
public class Logger extends Thread{
String input,path;
int matchNumber;
public Logger(String path0) {
    path=path0;
}
public void log (int matchesNumber0,String input0) {
    matchNumber=matchesNumber0;
    input=input0;
    this.run();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedWriter textWriter = null;
    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String stringDateToday = date.format(today);
    if(input!=null) {
        try {
            String logFilePath = path;
            textWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(logFilePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            textWriter.write(stringDateToday + "-----" + matchNumber + "-----");
            textWriter.write(input + "\n");
            if (!input.contains(" content=")) {
                setWarningMsg(input);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Incorrect Log File path!!!");
        } finally {
            try {
                textWriter.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[cmd Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbp2s.png)

Comment: Are you using MS Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the case that the text-editor you are using to view the file may not be able to decode the greek-text file correctly.

If you are on Unix (or with Cygwin on Windows) the `file` program may be able to help. This program looks at the first few bytes to try and guess the program which opens your file aptly. or else trying opening the file in `Intellij` itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
chcp 65001 && java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 path/to/your/runnable/jar
```

That solved my problem!

Comment: add the cmd output as an image